# Nested ng-repeat doesn't update object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to preset NxN matrix input to the user.  Therefore, I am using nested ng-repeat on a table object to create the input.  Although it initially populates successfully, it doesn't update the object.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="VibrationCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="Row in Mi">
      <td ng-repeat="I in Row track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="I">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  {{Mi}}
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function VibrationCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.Mi = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ];
}

myApp.controller('VibrationCtrl', VibrationCtrl);
```

JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wLhucx8b/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-model` needs to reference the actual part of the object (array), rather than simply the value.

```
ng-model="Row[$index]"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wLhucx8b/4/

Otherwise it will not update the actual object's reference. Imagine you're looping through an array and you just modify the value, rather than the reference in the array:

```
collection.forEach(function (value, index) {
  value = '123'; // this won't actually change the original array
  collection[index] = '123' // this WILL
});
```

^ `ng-repeat` with an `ng-model` on one of the values behaves the same way.

*Note: Use `<input type="number" ... />` or else your `ng-model` values will turn into strings!*

Comment: @DBordello I updated with an example of *why* this is the the way it is

Comment: @DBordello make sure to mark as answered if this resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="text" ng-model="I">
```

to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Row[$index]">
```

[Forked your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerdcarlson/czz7qtxc/2/)